# Redirect to another URL in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5

I want to redirect from one url to another is IIS.
For e.g. my page "Dynamic Graph Viewer" is available at http://localhost:8090
But want it to be available at http://localhost:8090/DynamicViewer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to redirect `http://localhost:8090` to `http://localhost:8090/DynamicViewer`? if so, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost:8090$" />
       </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:8090/DynamicViewer" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```